# Need to satisfy tolerance requirements to break out of for loop

Tags: python

Im writing code to minimize the three-hump-camel function using Gradient descent with constant step-size, and need to define a stopping criteria for the **for loop**. Criteria is the difference between previous and new point should be less than some tolerance value.

```
import numdifftools as nd
import numpy as np
#Gradient Method with Constant Step-Size 
def gradient(k):

    def eq(x): 
        return 2*(x[0]**2)-1.05*(x[0]**4)+(x[0]**6)/6+x[0]*x[1]+x[1]**2 #returns a multivariate function
    grad = nd.Gradient(eq)(k)

    return grad

def gdcss(initial_value,step_size,iterations):
    k0=initial_value
    k=k0
    kp1=[0,0]
    for i in range(iterations): 
        grad=gradient(k)
        kp1[0]=k[0]-step_size*grad[0]
        kp1[1]=k[1]-step_size*grad[1]
        
        print("Iteration number: ",i+1)
        print("The gradient of previous point is: ",grad)
        print("The new point is: ",kp1)
        xk=np.array(k)
        xkp1=np.array(kp1)
        e=np.subtract(xkp1,xk)
        tolerance=0.000001
        if e.all<tolerance:
            break
        k=kp1
    return []

gdcss([-1,2],0.1,70)
```

It is giving me the following error:
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'float'

Comment: You probably need something like `e.all(lambda x: x < tolerance)`.

Comment: Or `all([x < tolerance for x in e])`.